# adicionar mais de um nome no formulário

Tags: php, javascript, html5

Estou com o seguinte problema, tenho um *image map*, onde ao clicar nas coordenadas o resultado aparece dentro de um `<input type="text" />`, porém consigo colocar apenas o nome de uma das coordenadas clicadas.

Gostaria de saber como faço para inserir mais de um nome de coordenada dentro deste mesmo `input`.

**Segue o código:**

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
        function local(name){
           document.myform.post_localp.value = name
        }
    </script>

</head>

<body>
<form name="myform" action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="post_localp" size="20">

<div id="anterior" style="display:none" class="imgAnterior">
    <img src="imagem.png" alt="anterior" usemap="#tutorials">  &nbsp;                           
            <map name="tutorials">
                <area shape="rect" coords="142,284,185,308" href="#" alt="JE" onclick="local('J.E')">
                <area shape="rect" coords="209,284,249,308" href="#" alt="JE" onclick="local('J.D')">
                </map>    
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: agradeço o auxílio Valdeir, poderia me ajudar com alguma solução também?

Comment: Altere para `document.myform.post_localp.value += name`

Comment: dvd, deu certo da maneira que vc falou, o problema é que se clicar mais de uma vez na coordenada ela repete o resultado. Tem alguma maneira de evitar que isso aconteça?

Comment: Sim... Mas é bom sempre colocar na pergunta tudo que vc quer, por exemplo, "que não repita etc"...

Comment: entendi, é pq não tinha ideia de que isso poderia acontecer, vc por acaso saberia me dizer como fazer para que não se repita?

Answer (score 1):

É possível concatenando com o que já tem no `input`, e evitando que o mesmo seja inserido (na imagem abaixo, cada metade, esquerda e direita, é um link map):

```html
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
        function local(name){
           
           var valor = document.myform.post_localp.value;
           
           if(valor.indexOf(name) == -1){
              document.myform.post_localp.value += name+" ";
           }
        }
    </script>

</head>

<body>
<form name="myform" action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="post_localp" size="20">

<div id="anterior" style="xdisplay:none" class="imgAnterior">
    <img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" alt="anterior" usemap="#tutorials">  &nbsp;                           
            <map name="tutorials">
                <area shape="rect" coords="0,354,315,0" href="#" alt="JE" onclick="local('J.E')">
                <area shape="rect" coords="316,354,630,0" href="#" alt="JE" onclick="local('J.D')">
                </map>    
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: boa, muito obrigado mesmo. Só mais uma coisa, como faço para concatenar um espaço em branco entre o JD e o JE?

Comment: Resposta atualizada. :D Abs!

Comment: opaa, deu certinho brother. Muito obrigado!!

Comment: Legal amigo! Se puder é importante marcar a resposta com ✓ para finalizar

Comment: dvd, está por ai?

Comment: Estou sim......

Comment: opa, boa tarde amigo tudo bem? surgiu um novo problema, será que você poderia me ajudar?

Comment: diga aí, se eu puder ajudar

Comment: é o seguinte, fiz um formulário do tipo radio para que o usuário possa responder as perguntas e ai todas as respostas são apresentadas em uma página de relatórios, até ai tudo bem, o que eu quero fazer é apresentar uma imagem diferente para cada resposta selecionada. Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Cria as imagens baseadas nos valores das respostas: img_1.png, img_2.png etc... e carrega elas na página junto com a resposta

Comment: e qual o código uso pra chamar as imagens na página de relatórios? Pq para chamar as respostas eu estou utilizando o seguinte:  <tr class="table-row">
                <td> <center> <?php ?> </center> </td>
                <td> <center> <?php echo $row["nome"];?></center> </td>
                <td> <center> <?php echo $row["post_pos"]; ?> </center> </td>
                <td> <center> <?php echo $row["post_percepcao"]; ?> </center> </td>  </tr>

Comment: Use `<img src="img_1.png" />`

Comment: e como relacionar isso com o id da resposta? é preciso salvar a imagem no BD e fazer a chamada?

Comment: Relacionar com o id acho que não dá... Se vc não tem como relacionar alguma informação da resposta com a imagem que vc quer, é preciso criar uma coluna no BD, na mesma tabela das respostas, pra guardar o nome da imagem e puxar depois no relatório